# Get the absolute or dynamic path of the resources folder in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

is there a way to get the dynamic path of a resources folder in wpf application??
im currently searching for the solution for this matter but i cant find any article with regards on this matter

Comment: What resource folder are you talking about? In WPF, resources are typically embedded in the assembly file.

Comment: Are you talking during development or during the running of the application...

Comment: During running of application

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the full file path of the actual executing assembly using this line:

```
string appFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

Getting the path of your `Resources` folder from there shouldn't be hard... if I had know where you added it, I could have helped further. If you added it into the root directory of the project, then you should be able to access the correct file path doing something like this:

```
using System.IO;
...
string resourcesFolderPath = Path.Combine(
    Directory.GetParent(appFolderPath).Parent.FullName, "Resources");
```

Comment: the output of this code is in debug folder is there another way to locate it dynamically?

Comment: Really? You don't know how to manipulate a `string` file path? See my updated answer.

Comment: I will test it on installed application in my computer hope it didnt get any errors like it did before

Answer (score 1):

All situations where  you need to find things based on the running application, normaly I would look at reflection.

Say you want the folder below your executable, I would call something like

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

to determine where you are running and exend that path to go to a relative subpath.